# Как узнать маску подсети в windows

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно узнать ip адрес своей подсети в windows при помощи c++?
Я смог узнать свой ip таким образом

```
char ac[80];


    if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() <<
                " when getting local host name." ;
        return 1;
    }

    struct hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ac); //получаем информацию о хосте по имени хоста

if (phe == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Yow! Bad host lookup." ;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i) {
        struct in_addr addr;
        memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        std::cout << "Address " << i << ": " << inet_ntoa(addr) << std::endl;
        
    }
```

В моем случае `ip - 192.168.0.101`. Как я понимаю мне нужно узнать маску подсети и на ее базе получить свой ip подсети - `192.168.0.1`. В интернете прочитал, что нет api которое может вернуть маску подсети, как тогда можно ее узнать?

Comment: msdn GetNetworkParams https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getnetworkparams

Comment: ¿А хост обязательно должен знать маску подсети, в которой он работает? @nick_n_a ¿и где там маска подсети?

Comment: @user7860670 Да, там нету, надо в iphlp покопаться внимательно.

Comment: А зачем вам адрес "своей подсети"? Обычно нужен адрес DNS, если вам надо получить DNS имя. Только в  gethostbyname это уже реализовано.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo тут есть маска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На MSDN есть пример https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo

При желании их пример можно упростить.

По сути это вызов

```
IPHLPAPI_DLL_LINKAGE ULONG GetAdaptersInfo(
  PIP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo,
  PULONG           SizePointer
);
```

этой функции, а структура содержит маску.

Answer (score 0):

Если прямо уж так хочется, в Qt есть нужный метод:

```
QHostAddress QNetworkAddressEntry::netmask() const
```

> Returns the netmask associated with the IP address. The netmask is
> expressed in the form of an IP address, such as 255.255.0.0.
>
> For IPv6 addresses, the prefix length is converted to an address where
> the number of bits set to 1 is equal to the prefix length. For a
> prefix length of 64 bits (the most common value), the netmask will be
> expressed as a QHostAddress holding the address FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF::

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaddressentry.html#netmask

Не хотите зависимости от Qt - изучайте исходники чтобы понять, как она достает маску.